# Strictness of pattern matching vs. deconstructing

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation, fold

I'm trying to define primitive recursion in term of `foldr`, as explained in [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness on fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf) chapter 4.1.

Here is first attempt at it

```
simpleRecursive f v xs = fst $ foldr g (v,[]) xs
  where 
    g x (acc, xs) = (f x xs acc,x:xs)
```

However, above definition does not halt for `head $ simpleRecursive (\x xs acc -> x:xs) [] [1..]`

Below is definition that halt

```
simpleRecursive f v xs = fst $ foldr g (v,[]) xs
  where 
    g x r = let (acc,xs) = r
            in (f x xs acc,x:xs)
```

Given almost similar definition but different result, why does it differ? Does it have to do with how Haskell pattern match?

Comment: Probably related to a scoping issue with `xs`, since moving it to the definition of `g` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial difference between the two functions is that in

```
g x r = let (acc, xs) = r
        in (f x xs acc, x:xs)
```

The pattern match on the tuple constructor is irrefutable, whereas in

```
g x (acc, xs) = (f x xs acc, x:xs)
```

it is not. In other words, the first definition of `g` is equivalent to

```
g x ~(acc, xs) = (f x xs acc, x:xs)
```

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is there is some r which does not match (acc, xs) ?

Comment: doesn't the (v,[]) make sure that r is always in form of (acc,xs)?

Comment: No, because subsequent recursive calls to the function are not passed `(v, [])`, but whatever is returned by `g`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, just to confirm my understanding, the problem is (acc,xs) in second definition is strict, which make haskell evaluate acc and xs, which is defined by next iteration g, thus make haskell continue to infinity?